# What exactly is an advanced object cache?

Tags: cache

I'm reading [this article](https://eamann.com/tech/wordpress-fragment-caching/) about fragment caching. It seems self explanatory except for this line:

> based on the assumption that you have an advanced object cache available.

What exactly is an advanced object cache, and how can I check for one/implement if not already available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An advanced object cache is a cache mechanism that can store data that persists beyond a single request. A couple of popular object caches for WordPress are APC and Memcached. The [`WP_Object_Cache` class Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache) has [a list of links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Object_Cache#Persistent_Caching) with more info on advanced cache options.

Comment: So it's my understanding that using an advanced object cache like APC or Memcached are alternatives to using transients. Is this correct? Grossly oversimplified?

Comment: It's not necessarily an alternative, though it may remove the need for transients. The Transients API will use an object cache if it is available and configured via the `WP_Object_Cache` class, so it's not an either/or.

Comment: It's important to note that Zend's OpCache is bundled with PHP 5.5 and APC has major problems on versions above 5.5 and work in it has ceased.

Answer (score 6):

Without an advanced cache PHP execution looks like this:

[image]

With an advanced cache PHP's execution looks like this:

[image]

As you can see reading from memory is faster, much like on a personal computer when playing  a game,

*Images cutesy of engineyard.com*